# Java generic class "parameterized" by something extending an abstract class

Tags: java, generics

I have an `AbstractCacheBlock` and I want to define a class `CacheSet` that contains many classes extending `AbstractCacheBlock`. I believe what I want is something like

```
public class CacheSet<? extend AbstractCacheBlock>
```

But this doesnt appear valid. How can I refer to that class then? Usually it looks something like

```
public class CacheSet<T> {
    public void something() {
        T t = new T();
    }
```

What do I use in place of the `T` then?

Comment: Why do you want to create instances in a `CacheSet`? Shouldn't you be adding already created instances?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, maybe you are right I should initialize it outside

Answer (score 9):

The only way to intialize an instance of a generic type is by passing an instance of the Class, something like:

```
public class CacheSet<T>
{
    private Class<T> clazz;

    public CacheSet(Class<T> clazz)
    {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public void something()
    {
        T t = clazz.newInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: + probably something like: `public class CacheSet<T extends AbstractCacheBlock>{...}`

Answer (score 1):

Creating object with `T` is not doable. 
You can add dependency to class that can create a new `T` object.